# is it possible to use php api function in javajet code?

Tags: java, php, talend

I want to create a Talend component that based on javajet code, that talend component fetch data from one web based inventory system. But the thing is that the api of that system is available in php so I want to use that php api function in javajet code. is it possible?

Comment: Can you execute php code on your host out of the box?

Comment: Talend has only support for perl and java; that's why we can create .perljet and .javajet files in talend.Its thus not possible to excute php code in talend.I am therefore looking for any conversion method of the php code to java.

Answer (score 1):

The .javajet code generates plain Java, so you cannot embed or call PHP directly in that. But you should be able to call your PHP API by invoking the PHP interpreter as a subprocess in the generated code, e.g. by calling

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("php myapi.php").
```

You would then need to come up with a mechanism to pass arguments and results to/from the subprocess, preferably via command-line arguments and/or standard input and standard output.

Alternatively, you might want to invoke your PHP API through a web server, which means you would have to issue an HTTPRequest to that webserver and parse the response you get from the server.